# What is the counter name of given type of float?

Tags: counters

Reminder:

```
\newfloat{〈type〉}{〈placement〉}{〈ext〉}[〈within〉]
```

I use it as shown in the code below to create listings. My question is: what is the counter name associated with `<type>` (or `<ext>`)? I tried the obvious (see code), that didn't work, then looked into the [dtx file](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float) to figure out what it is, but couldn't.

```
\documentclass[full]{l3doc}
\usepackage{mwe} % TEST
\usepackage{float} % DOC

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{Listing}{h}{lop}

\begin{document}

% \setcounter{theListing}{9}    
\begin{Listing}
  \textbf{In:}

  \verb|\lipsum[1]|

  \textbf{Out:}

  \lipsum[1]

\end{Listing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAICS `\newfloat` just says `\newcounter{#1}`, so `\setcounter{Listing}{9}` should do it.

Comment: The macro `\the<countername>` (in your case `\theListing`) is also defined, but it only determines the output format of the counter. The counter itself is called `Listing`.

Comment: The float type and counter name are always the same (\@captype is set to the float type and used as the counter name).

Answer (score 1):

From the comments,

```
\documentclass[full]{l3doc}
\usepackage{mwe} 
\usepackage{float} 

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{Listing}{h}{lop}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{Listing}{10}

\begin{Listing}
  \textbf{In:}

  \verb|\lipsum[1]|

  \textbf{Out:}

  \lipsum[1]
    \caption{ }\label{foo}

\end{Listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]